# Problema al ingresar a phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema para ingresar al panel de control de phpMyAdmin,todo sucedió por que estoy haciendo una aplicación para Android en visual studio usando xamarin,en la que me pide mi usuario y contraseña, después de estar investigando del por qué no podía acceder a la base de datos desde la aplicación, [me topé con este documento](https://forums.asp.net/p/1961688/5604796.aspx?Web+Host+MySQL+Exception+Authentication+with+old+password+no+longer+supported+use+4+1+style+passwords+).

Entonces hice lo de agregar esas dos líneas de código en una pestaña que sale dentro del panel de control de phpMyAdmin (no recuerdo cual pestaña es) pero tiene un cuadro donde se puede poner código, bueno dejando de lado la aplicación de android, lo que hice fue poner estas dos líneas :

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=0; 
SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('YOURDATABASEPASSWORD');
```

Pero, se me olvidó cambiar la parte donde dice **"YOURDATABASEPASSWORD"**, y tal cual guardé. Y fue cuando quedé fuera del panel de control y me da el error **#1045**.

Y lo malo de todo es que tengo otra base de datos donde manejo un sistema de inventarios y tampoco puedo entrar desde el login que se implementó, en esa página me marca este error:

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'C191620_frank'@'98.130.0.220' (using password: YES)

Vaya esas dos líneas de código me dejaron fuera de todo.

¿Hay alguna manera de poder ingresar de nuevo?

Si es así, ¿pierdo lo que ya tengo en mis otras bases de datos?

Utilizo `ixwebhosting`, y los `PHP` se suben desde `Dreamweaver`.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado a entrar usando como contraseña `YOURDATABASEPASSWORD`? ¿Qué versión de MySQL estás usando? ¿Tienes acceso de `root` o cualquier otro usuario administrador? ¿Has tratado de contactar con soporte de tu hosting si tú no administras esa base de datos?

Comment: Gracias ,@OscarGarcia no se como no se me ocurrió , supongo que ya estaba muy cansado de buscar solución , tu respuesta es la solución , la contraseña efectivamente es YOURDATABASEPASSWORD ,ya pude acceder a el panel de control ,muchas gracias.

Comment: Te cedo la reputación. Ponte como respuesta eso y la marcas como correcta.

Comment: Disculpa pero soy nuevo en el foro, y funciona diferente de otros foros,como hago lo que me pediste ? @OscarGarcia

Comment: Debajo de tu pregunta hay una ventana para redactar respuestas (**Tu respuesta**). Escríbela allí y pulsa "Publicar Tu Respuesta" cuando termines. Es probable que tengas que esperar 24 o 48 horas antes de poder marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta.